# What does the "transactional" mode mean for RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I use RabbitMQ as a broker for [celery](/questions/tagged/celery) and I observe that some messages get dropped. While investigating the problem by looking into the web management UI, I've seen that channels have a "mode" (confirm or transactional).

What does it mean if a channel is transactional?

I only know the term from database systems. There it means that either the complete transaction is done or nothing of it. A transaction bundles some operations together and guarantees that they happen completely or not at all.

I read [the docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html) but it doesn't help me.

### Specific questions

> "Other operations such as resource creation/deletion are not transactional"

1. How can resource creation/deletion not be transactional? How can something be half deleted / created?

> "On the consuming side, the acknowledgements are transactional"

2. How could an acknowledgement possibly be not transactional?

Comment: I don't remember, but I don't think so.